# How to use cordova-plugin-android-permissions in Ionic 3?

Tags: cordova, ionic3, native

I am using a couple of cordova plugins like camera and Image Pickers in my App and they work great on all the Devices… but the problem comes for getting the Permission to these plugins from the phone. Below Android 6 Versions asks for these permissions while installing but Android 6 and above ask for these permissions only when for the first time when the user uses that plugin inside the application(i.e during the Runtime).

I found [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/) Ionic native plugin to handle these permissions in all versions of Android But exactly not getting how to use it or where to use it in my code, So If anyone has any Videos or know anything about it then please mention it here.

Thanks,

Comment: try this https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured it out how to use this native plugin. this is what I tried.

> Installed the Plugin as mentioned in [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/#PERMISSION) ionic doc

then in my app.component.ts file

```
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions';

constructor(platform: Platform, androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {

         androidPermissions.requestPermissions(
           [
             androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA, 
             androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CALL_PHONE, 
             androidPermissions.PERMISSION.GET_ACCOUNTS, 
             androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
             androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
           ]
         );

    }) 
}
```

I hope this will help someone. Thanks.

Comment: Hi and thanks for this answer, one further question, what about ios?