# Ionic app not getting data from remote API on Android device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

So i'm building an Ionic App with API calls, everything works fine when i run it on the browser and i get all my data.

But when i build the app (ionic cordova build android) and install the .apk in my phone, i get NO data, the view is just empty and i don't know why.

I followed instructions that i found [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-run-android-works-but-apk-does-not-access-internet/3867/14) but still nothing.

I even installed "*android-permissions*" cordova plugin as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47648849/how-to-use-cordova-plugin-android-permissions-in-ionic-3) but when i'm installling the app one my phone, it says that the app does not require any permission.

I'm lost and don't really know why it is not working. Help neede please !.

**Information about the project**

```
Created using "ionic start appName blank --type=angular"

Ionic Framework :

@ionic/angular 4.9.1

Ionic CLI :

5.4.1

Cordova CLI :

9.0.0

Cordova Platforms : 

android 8.1.0
```

Thank you

Comment: what are you using as your back-end?

Comment: I'm using PHP and MySql. The whole backend (php scripts + mysql database) is hosted on a web server

Comment: Have you tried to Debug your application via Chrome??

Comment: Use Chrome Debug tool to Check debug your app: To use Chrome Debug type `chrome://inspect/#devices` in your chrome Search bar.

Connect your Mobile(enable Developer option & USB debugging from settings) via Cable you will see your device slick on it a New debugger window will open. check console for errors / warnings.

Comment: No i haven't, but it is actually working on Chrome when i run the ionic serve command, everything works fine

Comment: Alright i will try it right now

Comment: I would suggest you to debug your app on device : https://medium.com/@coderonfleek/debugging-an-ionic-android-app-using-chrome-dev-tools-6e139b79e8d2

Comment: Usually, this happens because you haven't `Enabled CORS`, see how to enable CORS in php.

Comment: CORS is enabled in my PHP scripts and in the config.xml file as well there is <access origin="*" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a [whitelisting](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#network-request-whitelist) or, if you have Android 9 and your API does not use TLS, a [network security](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html) issue.

## Whitelisting

Add the tag `<access origin="https://your-server.com" />` to your `config.xml`.

## Network Security

To allow Android 9 devices to access `http://` (non-TLS) APIs, additional [configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html) is required. In a Cordova app, perform the following steps:

1. Create a file called `network_security_config.xml` in your project root containing the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <network-security-config>
        <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
      </domain-config>
    </network-security-config>
```

2. Add this to your `config.xml` to include the new configuration in your Android Manifest:

```
    <platform name="android">
        ...
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        ...
    </platform>
```

Rebuild the Android platform (i.e. `ionic cordova platform rm android` and `ionic cordova platform add android` etc.) and it should work from your device.

Comment: Alright thank you, i'm going to try it right now and come back

Comment: Does your endpoint use SSL? And does your request complete with a 200 response but there is not payload, or does the request error out?

Comment: No it does not use SSL. And the request responses with a 200 code. Everything works fine on the browser/computer. The problem is the Android device that i install the app on, i'm seeing no data. And i don't know if it is a CORS issue or something with the Android permissions (internet, network_state...)

Comment: Are you on Android 9? They require you to use SSL. Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie

Comment: Yes i'm on Android 9. Okay i'm going to take a look at the question and come back to you. Thanks

Comment: I updated the answer with instructions on adding the necessary config to an Ionic/Cordova app.

Comment: Hey, thanks to you i now know what was the issue. It's exactly what you said, the network security configuration with Android 9 because i tested the app on another phone runnig Android 5 and it's working just fine. But now after editing the project with the additional configuration that you just provided, the app is not working anymore on the Android 9 device, it starts then stops right away

Comment: What i did is that i did not create a new **network_security_config.xml** file, i found that it was existing on my project and it was referenced it the _config.xml_ , so i just edited it. Is that wrong?

Comment: The file was looking like this `<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>`

Comment: Hey @alex , it's finally working. I finally fixed it.I just had to edit the file adding this `<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>`

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot

Comment: @tonyStark hi I'm having the same issue.. can you please help me saying specifically what you did to solve the problem?

Comment: Hey @kavindhi , i'll be glad to help. I'm a little bit limited in the comments so i made a file that explains the issue and how to solve it. Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gco9J6su8lBgyF3wVt6lgDj8mD-DzY3A). I stay tuned for more questions

Comment: @kavindhi You're welcome, have your issue been fixed ?

Comment: @tonyStark yes. my problem happens due to iframe tag

Comment: @kavindhi Aight , glad to help